# What is the optimal strategy for this 2 player game?

Tags: ds.algorithms, pr.probability, gt.game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Let some finite array of integers is given initially.

There is a number k which is initially '0'.

In a move, a player will select a number from the array arr[i] and change k to gcd(k,arr[i]).

Also, the number chosen from the array(i.e a[i]) will be removed from that array.

CONSTRAINTS

A player who makes k=1 at any step loses.
A player who cannot move also loses.
2 players are playing the game optimally.

When will the player who moves first wins the game?

Comment: this seems related to the Sylver Coinage game: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylver_coinage

Comment: @mobiusdumpling I have seen that game before,But how can we reduce it to this one.

Comment: This seems to be identical to the problem http://www.codechef.com/MAY14/problems/SEAGM, which is a problem on a currently ongoing contest. It's probably best to at least wait until the contest is over before answering.